# Delphi iOS TMemo Scroll Versus Pan

Tags: ios, delphi

I have a readonly memo shwoing some text. However, there is a usability oddness. The user can pan the content in TMemo when only scroll ought to be possible.

Since people seem to think panning and scrolling is the same, I will give my definitions:

- Panning = You can drag the entire content top/bottom/left/right (i.e. all
  directions... NOT scrolling text but more like dragging entire "textview" object/widget. Also what is normally seen in image panning demos where you can pan the image in different directions to see e.g. top/bottom/left/right.)
- Scrolling of text = scrolling of text the direction the content in the widget is placed (e.g. scrolling text up/down)

My question is how to only have scroll if possible. (And **not** be able to drag 2/3 of the entire text control out of the view although i bounces back when touch is let go)

Comment: Do you have a question about this, or are you just sharing a cool story with us? :)

Comment: Aren't scrolling and panning the same things?

Comment: Panning with touch sensitive devices vs scrolling by clicking on scrollbars, performs the same operation. If there is a distinction in the TMemo component between the two operations, then please add that information to your question.

Comment: Panning = sideways dragging of content. Scrolling... Scrolls text down?

Comment: There is a property `ShowScrollBars` that defines the scrolling. If this property is true (default) and you have set a `HScrollBar` property of your Memo, then you have a "panning" component. Note that horisontal panning is called horisontal scrolling in most environments.

Comment: @LURD You write: "horisontal panning is called horisontal scrolling". Okay, I come from a Windows background where you can often scroll text horizontoally and vertically which is very different from what I am seeing. Hence, I wanted to describe the "dragging of content" (not scrolling as e.g. normal scrolling  on iOS, Android or Windows) as panning. Anyhow, I will check out the properties you mention :)

Comment: @LURD For reference, ShowScrollBars set tto true. No HScrollBar property.

Comment: What about `Memo.AniCalculations.BoundsAnimation := False;`? This should stop the bouncing effect.

Comment: @LURD That works. Thanks :) I will accept it as answer if you post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is an animation effect.

It can be turned off by setting the property:

```
AniCalculations.BoundsAnimation := false;
```

See [`FMX.InertialMovement.TAniCalculations.BoundsAnimation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.InertialMovement.TAniCalculations.BoundsAnimation) for more information.